# backup .git directory to the cloud using rsync

Tags: git

I am not using github for particular repositories.

I am currently using rsync to backup those `.git` directory to the cloud.

The way the sync works is:

- it over-write a file if it is modified.
- Delete a file if it is deleted.
- Add files if it is added.

Is it a safe way to backup `.git` directory (keep the integrity of the repository) or should I zip the directory and then put it in the cloud?

Comment: I'm afraid it may cause broken repository even after zipping (the result zip container may contain no new git objects in it if the something changed in the repository just after zipping started). Are `git fast-export` (produces a single file dump to be restored with `git fast-import`) or repo mirroring an option for you?

Comment: Yes, anything that helps mesave a copy of my repo in the cloud given it does not break the integrity of my repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transfer a repository safely with `rsync` if and only if the repository is completely quiescent (no operations, not even `git gc`, are running).  You should use `--delete-after` to ensure the integrity of the repository.

There is no way to safely transfer a busy repository except using `git fetch` or `git push`.

You can also use a tar archive to transfer an idle repository.  I would not use a zip file, since zip files usually compress, and Git data is already compressed, so you'll waste cycles for no benefit, and some zip file archivers don't handle large files correctly, nor do they typically transfer permissions.

Comment: Nice point for using `tar`! Is it possible to explicitly lock a Git repository for a while so that `tar` could walk the locked repository safely? Additionally, are there any other commands like `push` and `fetch` that are safe to run in busy repositories?

Comment: The current command I am using is `rsync -avh --omit-dir-times --delete --filter='protect .sync' --exclude=book-collection-and-scripts/ /media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/ /home/blueray/Yandex.Disk/`. Here `/media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/` has the `.git` directories. Should I replace `--delete` with `--delete-after`?

Comment: Yes, you should replace `--delete` with `--delete-after`.